# Method of DofnTester class for testing Dataflow's Dofn not found

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

SDK    : Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java 2.1.0
Class  : DoFnTester
Method : setOutputTags
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFnTester.html

The Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java 1.9.1 has setSideOutputTags.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFnTester

Is this method developed?
Is there an alternative test method for 2.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

These methods were indeed removed, because AFAIK they never really worked properly. `DoFnTester` itself [is being deprecated](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3159) and the recommended replacement is to use `TestPipeline` and `PAssert`.

Comment: Thank you, jkff.
I was able to test with your advice.
Thank you very much.